# if loop is not working? can anyone help me

Tags: java

```
public class meaingCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cnt = 0;
        String st1, u, st2;
        st2 = "funny";
        int n = 5;
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        st1 = in.nextLine();
        String[] v = st1.split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++) {
            if(v[i].equalsIgnoreCase(st2))
                cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt>=4)
            System.out.println("  match found");
    }
}
```

I am just a beginner in java.I want to get the output as match found if the no: of words in the input string match the word funny is greater than 4 but the if loop is not working.

Comment: Define not working, and `if` is not a loop,

Comment: Please provide some sample incorrect output and expected output.

Comment: It can't. There is a syntax error: missing `{`.

Comment: @weirdpanda no he didn't: you missed the opening bracket because the class declaration wasn't formatted properly (it's now fixed). If you want, you can go back to the [initial revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33706044/revisions) and see it.

Answer (score 2):

Your stop condition in the for loop is wrong: since you're looping on the array of strings `v` you should stop when you've reached the last element. Modify:

```
for(int i=0;i<st1.length();i++)
```

to:

```
for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

when traversing due to this **st1.length()** we get ArrayIndexOutofBoundException so compare with array length instead of strings length.
This works:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int cnt=0;
        String st1,u,st2;
        st2="funny";
        int n=5;
          System.out.println("Enter the string");
          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
          st1=in.nextLine();
          String[]v=st1.split("\\s+");
          for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++)
          {
              if(v[i].equalsIgnoreCase(st2))
               cnt++; 

           }
            if(cnt>=4)
          System.out.println("  match found");

            }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such thing as an `if` loop. You have a `for` loop.

Your problem is that in your for loop, you check if `i` is less then the length of the String st1. However you need to check if `I` is less then the length of the array `v`. So, change this statement:

```
for(int i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++)
```

to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
```

Hope this helped.